# How to enhance ngSanitize whitelists?

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm trying to append HTML content from the controller to the view. For this I know that we have to use `ngSanitize`. Everything is  working fine, but it is stripping out the attributes of the HTML elements.

Here is my controller:

```
var modalVar = '<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal'+ data.data.id +'" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Alert</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><p>Are you sure to delete?</p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteFunc('+ data.data.id +')" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button></div></div></div></div>';

$scope.modalsDiv = $scope.modalsDiv + modalVar;
```

The view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="modalsDiv"></div>
```

If I inspect and see the rendered elements, every div element is rendered but their attributes are stripped out.

Comment: Explanation is in the documentation .... RTFM

Comment: @charlietfl so you mean there is no way to extend ngSanitize

Comment: Don't have to extend it if you read the manual. The method you need is there

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should not be adding HTML to the view.

```
<!--REPLACE ng-html-bind 
  <div ng-bind-html="modalsDiv"></div>
-->
<!--WITH ng-if -->
  <div ng-if="showModal">
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal{{data.data.id}} +'" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
              Alert
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure to delete?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-danger" 
                    ng-click="deleteFunc(data.data.id)" 
                    data-dismiss="modal">
               Yes
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
   //$scope.modalsDiv = modalVar;

   $scope.showModal = true;
```

Instead of composing HTML in the controller, use the `ng-if` directive. The code will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller:
someVar = $sce.trustAsHtml('someVar');
do not forget to inject $sce into ctrl